# Can \cref be made to ignore spaces?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, arguments

I think this MWE says it all. `\cite` can ignore spaces in its argument, while `\cref` cannot. I wonder if `\cref` could be improved that way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{1, author="One Author", year=2000}
    @misc{2, author="Another Writer", year=2010}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    We can use \cite{1,2} AND \cite{1, 2}!

    Yet, we can use \cref{1,2}, but not \cref{1, 2}!

    \section{Section 1}
    \label{1}

    \section{Section 2}
    \label{2}

    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Why is this important? Because some text editors, TeXstudio being one of them, have trouble implementing line wraps at commas without a subsequent space.

Comment: Is using LuaLaTeX an option for you?

Comment: Related topic [spaces in lists](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/docsvlist.shtml#spacesinlists).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Normalization with removal of spaces before and after label names and removing of empty entries.

The following example uses the comma parser of package `kvsetkeys` for parsing the label name list of the referencing commands of package `cleveref`. The internal `\@cref` with the list in its second argument is redefined for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}

\makeatletter
\let\org@@cref\@cref
\renewcommand*{\@cref}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \toks@={}%
    \comma@parse{#2}\add@cref@item
  \edef\process@me{\endgroup
    \noexpand\org@@cref{#1}{\the\toks@}%
  }\process@me
}
\newcommand*{\add@cref@item}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\\\the\toks@\\%
    \toks@{#1}%
  \else
    \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@,#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    We can use \cref{1,2}, and now  \cref{1, 2},\\
    and even with a leading or trailing comma: \Cref{ , 1 , 2 ,}.

    \section{Section 1}
    \label{1}

    \section{Section 2}
    \label{2}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Removal of open spaces and retaining commas

Solution that zaps all open spaces. If a label contains spaces, the label must be put in curly braces.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}

\makeatletter
\let\org@@cref\@cref
\renewcommand*{\@cref}[2]{%
  \edef\process@me{%
    \noexpand\org@@cref{#1}{\zap@space#2 \@empty}%
  }\process@me
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    We can use \cref{1,2}, and now  \cref{1, 2}.

    \section{Section 1}
    \label{1}

    \section{Section 2}
    \label{2}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\zap@space` is defined in the LaTeX kernel and is used to normalize options list for classes and packages, for example.

Comment: This answer has one drawback: `\cref{1,2,3,,4}` (sections 1-3 and 4) shall behave differently from `\cref{1,2,3,4}` (sections 1-4). This behavior is documented in `cleveref`, yet lost with this solution.

Comment: @bers See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your second example does not even need `\usepackage{kvsetkeys}`.

Answer (score 8):

Almost self-explaining code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{1, author="One Author", year=2000}
    @misc{2, author="Another Writer", year=2010}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:Nc \bers_cref:nn { @cref }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bers_cref:nn { nx }
\cs_set_protected:cpn { @cref } #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_bers_cref_seq { , } { #2 }
  \bers_cref:nx { #1 } { \seq_use:Nn \l_bers_cref_seq { , } }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_bers_cref_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

We can use \cite{1,2} AND \cite{1, 2}!

Yet, we can use \cref{1 space,2}, but also \cref{1 space, 2}!

Also \cref{1 space,2 , 3,, 4}

Also \Cref{1 space, 2, 3 , , 4}

\section{Section 1}
\label{1 space}

\section{Section 2}
\label{2}

\section{Section 3}
\label{3}

\section{Section 4}
\label{4}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I redefine the internal command `\@cref` to first split its second argument at commas, which removes leading and trailing spaces, but preserves inner ones. The original `\@cref` is saved in `\bers_cref:nn`, and then `\@cref` is redefined to use `\bers_cref:nx`, a variant that fully expands its second argument where we do `\seq_use:Nn` with a comma between entries.

Note that also `\Cref` is modified automatically. Empty entries are honored.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It allows whitespace (spaces, tab characters, line breaks) in the arguments of `\cref`, `\Cref`, and `\labelcref`. Note that the approach pursued in this solution doesn't modify the `cleveref` macros in any way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{luacode}
```

```lua
\begin{luacode}
function nospace ( t ) -- remove all whitespace characters from string "t"
  return ( t:gsub ( "%s", "" ) )
end
function crefnospace ( s ) 
  return ( s:gsub ( "\\.-[cC]ref%s-%b{}" , nospace ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
   "process_input_buffer", crefnospace, "crefnospace" )}}

\begin{document}
We may use \cref{a,b}, \Cref{a, b}, \cref{a ,b}, and \Cref{{ a }, b }.
``\labelcref{ b , {a }}'' works too.

\section{Section 1}\label{a}
\section{Section 2}\label{b}
\end{document}
```