# Cleveref reference list does not work with chapters

Tags: cleveref

I'm trying to use cleveref's reference list feature to refer to multiple chapters. However, the second in the list, no matter which order, is never found. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

(see \cref{chap:bar, chap:foo})

\chapter{Foo}
\label{chap:foo}
\lipsum

\chapter{Bar}
\label{chap:bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Attempting to compile results in the text "chapter 2 and ??"

Comment: There musn't be white space after the comma: `\cref{chap:bar,chap:foo}`

Comment: See also [Can \cref be made to ignore spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340492/5001)